# Drain pipe at wrong angle. What are the consequences?

Tags: drain

A friend of mine is asking me about severity of the problem she has with the drain pipe under her kitchen faucet. The pipe was installed horizontally, but now for some reason (I suspect the main drain pipe behind the wall was moved) it is at wrong angle, down from the horizontal by several centimeters.

[image]

What are the consequences of keeping it this way for a prolonged period of time?

*P.S. Sorry about my English, please tell me in comments if there are any unclear/wrong wording. Thanks.*

Comment: Note: in some places drum or bottle traps are not permitted, unless approved by the Authority Having Jurisdiction (AHJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The low point is where semi-solid materials (sludge, in our vernacular) will collect and ultimately clog the sink. If your friend is willing to clean the pipe out regularly, then it's probably okay.

As you probably know, the solution is to fix the plumbing and let water run downhill.

(Edited to respond to the comment/question about possible leakage.)

I'd say that the quality of the connection and the likelihood of it leaking is a different matter. A little bit of backed up water won't create a leak. However, if the plumbing was done poorly in the first place (and it looks like it was), then it might leak. While water is running, try to gently move some of the parts and see if there's a leak. If there is, the system needs to be repaired.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar system in my kitchen and the angle of you pipe is defiantly wrong. You will have some acclamation of water at this point and if not used for a while it will start to stink as the water will be stagnant. It will also collect what ever food  stuff that is washed down the drain that is not caught by the top "P" Trap. You could place another "P" Trap under this piper and clean it from time to time or correct the angle of the pipe so water runs more freely to the drain. This should mot create any leaks over a short period of time, but as they say "Prevention is better than cure"
Regards
P